# JSch Exception while using ecdh as kex algorithm

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, ecdsa

I am working on FIPS requirement for which i have to use ecdh-sha2-nistp384 as kex algorithm. I changed the config by using

```
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig("CheckKexes", "");
        session.setConfig("kex", "ecdh-sha2-nistp384");
        session.setConfig("ssh-rsa", "ecdsa-sha2-nistp384");
```

When I am putting this in the code the issue is I am getting the following exception.

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: verify: false
```

which seems like too generic to me. I serached a lot but did not find any person using ecdh for kex using JSch any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us [JSch log](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Logger.java.html).

Comment: I doubt that `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` conforms to FIPS. You lose any security by using that!

Comment: Yes it is true in FIPS it may not work. I put it just for testing purpose.

Comment: Where's the log? + Why did you add `session.setConfig("ssh-rsa", "ecdsa-sha2-nistp384");`? There's no `ssh-rsa` settings.